# Как в node red отправить сообщение по tcp кому-то определенному?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

1. Принимаю сообщение по tcp.
2. Запоминаю соединения
3. Делаю инъекцию

Хочу отправить по tcp НЕ ВСЕМ, а КОНКРЕТНО ОДНОМУ НУЖНОМУ соединению.
Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно передавать _session иначе будет происходить отправка всем